# Apply .not() (or .off()) for .one() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the following function, where I need to edit the code so, that the 'home' object can be clicked again. I've read that the `:not()` and `.off()` methods are used for it, but I can't make them work properly with the `.one` method.  The whole Idea is to disable the clicks on every other object, so that I can create a line starting and ending with the same object. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var Result = 0;
  var stop_process = false;
  $('img').one('click', function () {
    if (!stop_process) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('home')) {
        stop_process = true;
        if (Result == 10)
          $('body').append('<div class="message">Your Result is: </div>' + distanz);
        else
          $('body').append('<div class="message">Go through all Points!</div>');
      }
      if ($('img.home').length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('home');
      }
      var $elem1 = $(this).parent();
      var $elem2 = $('span.last');
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
      if ($elem2.length > 0) {
        connect($elem1[0], $elem2[0], "#0F0", 5);
      }
      else {
        $elem1.addClass('last');
      }
      $('span').removeClass('last');
      $elem1.addClass('last');
      Result++;
    }
  });
});
```

The full code : http://jsfiddle.net/JPr9r/

Comment: "The whole Idea is to disable the clicks on every other object" every other object, other images??? `$('img').on('click.custom',function(){$('img').off('click.custom'); ...});` ???

Comment: Yes, I mean other images. I know it is supposed to look like this, but whenever I try to edit it, it doesn't do what it's supposed to. Can you please edit the jsfiddle with the function you wrote. Thanks.